# Линейный односвязный список. Соединить два списка

Tags: c++

Как можно объединить в данном случае два списка в один?
Если я сделаю u2=u; То я получу только копию первого списка, а как еще получить второй список u1?
То есть на выходе я должен получить список: 1 2 3 3

```
class _List{
private:
    List* newList;
public:
    _List() {
        newList = NULL;
    }
void additem(int d);
void additem2();
void Prints();
};

void _List::additem(int d){
List* createList = new List;
createList -> d.a = d;
createList -> next = NULL;
List* x = new List;
if (newList != NULL) {
   x = newList;
   while ((x->next) != NULL){
        x = x->next;
   }
   x -> next = createList;
}else{
    newList = createList;
}
}

void _List::Prints() {
List* p = newList;
cout <<"Spisok: =";
while (p){
    cout<<p->d.a<<" ";
    p=p->next;
}
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
_List u;
_List u1;
_List u2;
u.additem(1);
u.additem(2);
u.additem(3);
u1.additem(3);
u.Prints();
u1.Prints();
getch();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: обычно последнему элементу 1 списка `p->next = u2`

Comment: @pavel На этот элемент ссылка идет, не получается так сделать. А как сделать в классе метод, догадаться не могу

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во-первых, у Вас в функции `_List::additem` есть утечка памяти. Замените нужную строку на следующую

```
List* x; // = new List;
```

Во-вторых, есть 2 способа объединить списки.
Первый уже назвали. В конец первого списка пишем указатель на второй. Уничтожение второго списка повлечёт ошибки в первом. Никаких трудностей реализации не вижу.
Второй способ - копирование второго списка в конец первого. Для этого объявляем функцию `void _List::additem(_List &list);` и её реализация очень проста:

```
void _List::additem(_List &list) {
    List* x = list.newList;
    while (x != NULL) {
        additem(x->d.a);
        x = x->next;
    }
}
```

Объединение происходит следующим образом:

```
_List u;
_List u1;
_List u2;
// Заполнение двух списков
u2.additem(u);
u2.additem(u1);
u2.Prints();
```